# per pixel drawing in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d

I used to write small games with 'per pixel' drawing, 
I mean with some SetPixel(x,y,color) function or such.

I am also interested in OpenGL but do not know it much.

Is it a good (fast) way to do a per pixel drawing in OpenGL ?

It would be good for example to use textured quads as a sprites,
or whole application background screen, with possibility to 
set distinct pixel with some kind of my own SetPixel routine
i would write... or any other way - but it should be efficient
as much as it cans

(especialy im interested in basic fundamenta 1.0 version of OGL)

Comment: By the way, OpenGL 1.0 may sound like the most basic, but actually OpenGL 1.1 is really the least common denominator. I've never seen a platform that didn't support at least 1.1 (and be it in software). In 1.0 You don't have texture objects and neither vertex arrays.

Comment: all right, tnx much, its good to know

Answer (score 6):

You can set a projection that will map vertex coordinates 1:1 to pixel coordinates:

```
glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, window_width, 0, window_height, -1, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

From here on, vertex X,Y coordinates are in pixels with the origin in the lower left corner. In theory you could use the immediate mode with GL_POINT primitives. But it's a much better idea to batch things up. Instead of sending each point indivisually create an array of all the points you want to draw:

```
struct Vertex
{
    GLfloat x,y,red,green,blue;
};

std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
/* fill the vertices vector */
```

This you can OpenGL point to…

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

/* Those next two calls don't copy the data, they set a pointer, so vertices must not be deallocated, as long OpenGL points to it! */
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].x);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].red);
```

…and have it access and draw it all with a single call:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertices.size();
```

Comment: Much TNX, i will check this - but can this arrays be large for many pixel drawings, say 10k 100k 1M ? can i delete it to 0 and fill it with my pixel drawing routines, again, each frame?

Comment: @user982377: Well, you shouldn't use it to draw whole pictures (use textures for that), it's more things like drawing a plot. Technically there's only the limitation of the index data type, but performance wise you should not batch up more than 2^16 points for performance reasons. Filling it with new data is no problem, however after resizing the base address will probably change so it needs to be reset. The point is: Manipulate single pixles makes only sense for sparse image manipulation. If you're doing bulk business, textures are the way to go.

Comment: @user982377: Also don't forget the CPU power required to compute those new pixels. Calculating 1M new values each frames will probably stall the GPU, because the CPU doesn't keep up with it. You should just tell us, what you plan to do, so we maybe can suggest something better.

Comment: I dont know if you can look at my simple progs (windows executable): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/bociaki5.zip   and http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42887985/unpack%20aeroplane%20pack.zip  It is all done by setpixel in GDI - it is like that I much like  "I have got setpixel i can think  what to do " way of making progs -  i want to do 2d things in such way - not to thinking of untouchable sprites as in openGl untouchable quad textures: Noe I see 2 options - with arrays you mention or with uploading whole quad texture to gpu each frame... so I repaeat i need "general 2d setpixel way" under ogl

Comment: (sometimes it also not must be set pixel it may be DrawLine(x,y,x2,y2,color) also (for 2d physics tests)

Comment: @user982377: Then my suggested method would be probably the way to go. You can switch GL_POINTS to GL_LINES or GL_LINE_STRIP to get DrawLine behaviour. You could also use the immediate mode, but as soon as you're going to draw more than 10 lines in a frame the array method should be used.

Comment: i will check both possibilities (GL_POINTS and 'ram_buffer[] as quadtexture to gpu each frame 'uploading''), some person also mention 'shader code' pixel modiffications on higher OGl versions (I know OGl only a very little) - any other possibilites doeas not come to ones mind? It is sad that simple 2d efficient blitting (to whole viewport or single textured quad cannot be very efficiently done) It really can not?

Comment: much tnx for example with glDrawArrays :)

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do this.

> Is it a good (fast) way to do a per pixel drawing in OpenGL ?

There is no good or fast way to do this. It is highly discouraged due to the speed.

The proper way, although not easy (or in some cases possible) in OGL 1, is to use pixel shaders or blend modes. That is the only correct way, anything else is hacking around the entire system.

Depending on how the data needs modified, vertex colors and blend modes may be able to solve the some uses. It won't tint each pixel individually, but you can modify the texture must faster.

To do it, you can draw single-pixel quads (although care must be taken to offset them and handle filtering to prevent blurring) or you can get texture data and manipulate it later. Both will be unbelievably slow, but could function.

Working with the texture data is probably simpler and may be slightly faster.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, especially since he wants OGL 1.0.

Comment: shaders are not option for me because I am talking about very basic dundamental ogl 1.0 or max 1.3; the last option you mention if I mean it is 'whole texture transfer' from gpu to ram and back is also bad really - so does it mean that doing it in maybe not fast but only moderate way it is imposible? very bad news

Comment: "This doesn't really answer the question", but it is useful so tnx, but maybe some more can be done though

Comment: user982377: If you have to manually edit any data, there is no chance of it being evenly vaguely fast, it's going to be extremely slow. It'll be even worse if you're on a limited platform (say, mobile), which is already slow.

Comment: Ideally it would be to get a "unsigned char pixelBuffer[y][x][3]" in RAM and to find efficient way how to 'blit' it to OGL surface or better quadtexture... (I use pc/windows but assume very weak integrated graphic cards with OGL max 1.3)

Comment: You may be able to improve things a *little* bit by keeping the texture data in RAM and creating a texture from it each frame or change. It will still be slow, and the texture will be write-only (reading back will have an even larger performance cost).

Comment: Yeah, that's his best bet. I did exactly that, for fun, when porting Descent to Windows. The game still uses a software renderer to render to a RAM-based buffer, which I used to texture a fullscreen quad in OpenGL.

Comment: ok, i will do time tests how slow is such texture to gpu each frame uploading